# How to change links structure in database by using query

Tags: mysql, database

How I can change links structure that embedded in posts by MySQL query in database?
For example I want to change links structure like this: (First line to second)

```
http://forum.site.com/thread1001.html
http://forum.site.com/index.php?app=forums&module=forums&controller=topic&id=1001
```

Is this possible? If not, is there another way?
Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking to do some string manipulation in MySQL, yeah?

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(url_field, "/", 3),
    "/index.php?app=forums&module=forums&controller=topic&id=",
    SUBSTRING(
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(url_field, "/", -1),
        ".",
        1
      ),
      7
    )
  )
;
```

To make this an `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET url_field = 
  CONCAT(
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(url_field, "/", 3),
    "/index.php?app=forums&module=forums&controller=topic&id=",
    SUBSTRING(
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(url_field, "/", -1),
        ".",
        1
      ),
      7
    )
  )
;
```

If you've got this URL embedded inside a `TEXT` or something (like a user comment) then you'll have to do a little more work to extract the URL from within it:

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(@url_field, "http://", 1),
    "http://",
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@url_field, "http://", -1), "/", 1),
    "/index.php?app=forums&module=forums&controller=topic&id=",
    SUBSTRING(
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(@url_field, "/", -1),
        ".",
        1
      ),
      7
    ),
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@url_field, "http://", -1), ".html", -1)
  )
;
```

Or to `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET text_field =
  CONCAT(
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(text_field, "http://", 1),
    "http://",
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(text_field, "http://", -1), "/", 1),
    "/index.php?app=forums&module=forums&controller=topic&id=",
    SUBSTRING(
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(text_field, "/", -1),
        ".",
        1
      ),
      7
    ),
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(text_field, "http://", -1), ".html", -1)
  )
;
```

Progressively complex in SQL only I'm afraid.  (You could optimize the above.)

To keep the number of altered records to a minimum - ensure a good `WHERE` clause on the end.

---

Explanation:

```
SET @url_field :=  "abcdedef http://forum.site.com/thread1001.html xyz";
SELECT
  -- CONCAT(
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(@url_field, "http://", 1), -- Everything left of URL
    "http://", -- Restore the http:// lost in the substring above
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@url_field, "http://", -1), "/", 1), -- Get the website domain name
    "/index.php?app=forums&module=forums&controller=topic&id=", -- Append the parts of our new URL we know won't change
    SUBSTRING(
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(@url_field, "/", -1), -- Get the ID from the original URL - starting at final /
        ".", -- ... stopping at .html
        1
      ),
      7 -- ... dropping the word "thread" from the start
    ),
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@url_field, "http://", -1), ".html", -1) -- capture everything after the URL
  -- )
;
```

Be aware this may break other URLs.  Unfortunately in MySQL we have no regex replacements etc without plugins/extensions (to my knowledge).

Comment: thanks for your response! but not for SELECT, I'm looking for REPLACE.

Comment: That's fine, you can just change it to UPDATE ... I'll amend my answer.